# Raspberry Pi 2, ROS and GPIO access

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, sudo, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

I just created two nodes:

- One is on my notebook to send status updates of a LED (the message is of type Bool)
- The other is on my RPi2 and sets the GPIO 17 to high/low according to value in the Bool message received

Both platforms are running ROS Indigo (notebook has Debian Jessie and  RPi2 has Raspbian Wheezy). I'm also using only Python (especially on the RPi2 this seems to be the much easier way to do things related to the GPIO).

My problem is the GPIO access requires superuser privileges, which rosrun doesn't seem to like (in fact rosrun obviously is not a known command when using sudo). My question is in what best way am I to handle this situation? Should ROS on such an embedded system actually be installed as root because of all the low level access to the hardware underneath or is it possible to execute rosrun in superuser temporarily just for that the time the specific node that requires such privileges is running?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216441/raspberry-pi-2,-ros-and-gpio-access/) by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 299 on 2015-08-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a long struggle I finally got it. There is actually no need to use `sudo` at all (or modify user/user groups) if you use the [wiringPi](http://wiringpi.com/) library. It has a command line utility called `gpio` which has an export function that makes the GPIOs accessible without the need for sudo both in Python and C/C++.

**UPDATE:** Since Raspbian Jessie the access to the GPIOs no longer requires `sudo`.

---

Originally posted by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) with karma: 299 on 2015-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-05-30**:
dont we have to subscribe the gpio pin values or something ? Can u directly access the gpio pins inside the ros node, just by using the library, and using its name at header file? thanks for giving easy answer, by the way.

**Comment by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on 2016-05-30**:
If I recall correctly you don't have to use any [command line tools](http://wiringpi.com/the-gpio-utility/) but you do have to set the pins you want to use as ins or outs. Code-wise you can put the calls to the `wiringPi` library anywhere in your node since this has nothing to do with ROS.

**Comment by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on 2016-05-30**:
How you control the pins remotely is a different topic. You can create a service for example, which runs on your ROS on the Pi and then trigger it remotely from your PC where another ROS is running (don't forget the master-slave thing with multiple ROS in the same network).

**Comment by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on 2018-04-13**:
I have the same issue but exporting the pin is not helping: `$ gpio export 17 out`, same error: `wiringPinSetup: Must be root`. gpio v 2.32 and ROS kinetic. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You shouldn't run ROS as root anywhere. The problem why `rosrun` cannot be found using `sudo` is that you haven't set up ROS for this.

Why not allow access to the (required) low level devices? See [this link about general unix file permissions](http://www.penguintutor.com/raspberrypi/file-permissions-reference) and [this link about how to use udev rules on an RPi](http://raspberrypi.znix.com/hipidocs/topic_gpiodev.htm) for setting file permissions for the GPIOs (on the very bottom of the page).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-08-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on 2015-08-25**:
This seems to offer a solution for a single application. Is there a way to enable non-root access to all GPIOs? Also I've read that Python has issues with such things (not to mention that one needs to modify the root configuration files like .bashrc to add the ROS and catkin workspace paths).

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-08-26**:
No, this is not for an application, but for a user group (second link). Thus, all members of this group have access, with all programs/applications they want.

Python has "issues with such things"? Whicht things?

And excatly why you would need to change the root `.bashrc`, sudo is not the way to go

**Comment by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on 2015-08-26**:
I did change to root's `.bashrc`. I added 3 paths there - the one in /opt/ros/.../dist-packages, another one from the catkin_ws (again dist-packages for Python2.7) and finally the one from /usr/lib/.../dist-packages. It is still complaining. I even changed my root to keep the PYTHONPATH (->sudoers)

**Comment by [rbaleksandar](https://answers.ros.org/users/14216/rbaleksandar/) on 2015-08-26**:\

> The script changes the group of the files to the group passed in ( gpio ) and changes the permissions mode of the files to 0660

Ah, I missed that.